# php_uploadprogress wamp refresh information

Tags: php, upload, wamp, progress

Did anyone used php_uploadprogress extension for wamp?

When i try to use it with jquery, only the fist is relevant, and all other request show an not-updated information.

The configuration is the fallowing:

```
  uploadprogress.file.filename__template=C:\wamp\tmp\upload_progress_%s.txt
  uploadprogress.get_contents=0
  uploadprogress.update_interval=500
```

Pleasa tell me where can be the problem.

Comment: Have you tried the APC module?

Comment: First i tried APC, but on Windows 2003 it works only with one update at a time. That' why I chose php_uploadprogress

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a patch for windows. It seams that the .dll provided by xampp and wamp does not work well.

If anyone need the patch, it can be found here: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/scripting/Useful_PHP_Extensions.aspx. You need to download the fist file: 'PHP_UploadProgress' and replace the 'php_uploadprogress.dll' from your extensions folder with one from 'Extension Windows' folder.